# Robotium : building test project using Ant when only apk file is available

Tags: ant, build, apk, robotium

I have created an Android test project using Robotium. For my own android project, I build the project successfully using following commands :

1. android update test-project -m /home/jyoti/workspacetry/Puresms/ -p /home/jyoti/workspacetry/ExampleApplicationTesting/
2. ant clean debug

Next I have created project for a apk file whose project is not available. I changed package name and MainActivity name in both xml and java file of test project. I do want to compile the project in a script using ant. But android update command not working without complete project name to be tested.

So how can i create a test project of Robotium using ant when i only do have apk file of project to be tested.